# Should I flag spam accounts even if they didn't post any content yet?

Tags: discussion, flags, user-accounts, spam

Every day I see many of such accounts being created. They rarely post spam (probably because they get blocked by the system) and if they do post spam content they are sometimes nuked by mods. I am not sure what is the purpose of creating them if the profile pages are rarely seen by anyone unless they post some content. They do contain spam in their profiles quite often, though.

It would not be very difficult to write an automated bot to watch these accounts and catch any content as soon as it is posted. My question is however, should we even bother to pre-emptively look for such spam accounts and watch what they are doing or mod-flag them before they do anything. (Mods could decline such flags based on lack of evidence).

Some examples from the past 20 minutes:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/13122747/p8lbtgh097
https://stackoverflow.com/users/13122731/graves-stack
https://stackoverflow.com/users/13122660/e6rsbjv278
https://stackoverflow.com/users/13122721/x1bztzn542
https://stackoverflow.com/users/13122719/koch-mangum
https://stackoverflow.com/users/13122811/l1hwuph301
https://stackoverflow.com/users/13122767/bjerg-foged